# how to remove what setpixel put on the window?? (c++)

Tags: c++, screen, pixel

im using SetPixel to make stuff on my window which is the easyest because i only want to set one pixel at a time. SetPixel is great but i need to remove the color every time i update it, i could overwrite the color by black but.. it's a really big waste of time is there some way i can over write all of the colors to black? (i would like something that is faster then reseting them all to black). i make a window and then color with setpixel (there is other ways (to draw on the window) but i only want to set one pixel/color at a time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should typically create a bitmap, lock it, set and unset its pixels directly - possibly by direct access rather than using API calls, if there are a lot of updates - unlock and then invalidate the window so that your paint handler can blit the bitmap later.

If you want to restore pixels, you can keep two bitmaps and store the values to restore in one bitmap.